# SQL Server view keeps restoring to original state

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server question and it centres around why a view when redefined and saved, would roll back to its original state - am I on the right track thinking about recovery models? could someone advise where to start please?

Some background to the environment:

We have a standard production DWH environment which consists of staging, data and reporting database areas that rebuilds every morning bringing data through from our source.

The problem only appears to be affecting some objects when the definition is changed - weird, any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What is the process that populates the DW tables? SSIS packages?

Comment: We have a parrallel environment which is loaded nightly (SSIS) we then take data from here and push in our IUD to our reporting DB

Comment: I would check out the packages associated with the tables that are changing. Sounds like maybe a drop/create of the views and/or tables somewhere in the packages.

Comment: Thanks @JacobH  - I did consider investigating our staging and data db creation process but thinking a bit more about it, the view that rolled back today was a recently changed one on our reporting DB which is outside the staging and data DB process?